# Find the shortest string by categories R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am quite a beginner in R, and I faced this problem.

I would like to find the length of the shortest string per each category in my tibble and then,
truncate all strings from the category according to width of the shortest one.

```
  ex = tibble( category = c("A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A"),
           string = c("cat", "bird", "apple", "cloud", "banana", "elephant"))
```

I presume how to solve the problem theoretically, however, I am not able to put it together.

```
ex %>% 
 group_by(category) %>%
 mutate(length = lapply(ex, function(x) min(nchar(x))) ) %>%
 somehow str_trunc() ?
```

At the end I would like to see something like that:

```
ex = tibble( category = c("A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A"),
    string = c("cat", "bir", "apple", "cloud", "banan", "ele"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need

```
ex %>% 
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(length = min(nchar(string)),
         string = str_sub(string, 1, length))
```

We don't need the `lapply` inside the mutate to find the length. We can just run that transformation on the `string` column directly. And here I used `stringr::str_sub` to get the substring with the right number of characters since you already seem to be using tidyverse functions. You could also use the base `substr` function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in base R with

```
aggregate(ex$string, list(ex$category),
    function(s) min(nchar(as.character(s))))
```